# Cocos2d-JS and Javascript codes

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

Is it possible for someone to extract the original Javascript code from a compiled IPA or APK or is the code converted to native code?

Answer (score 0):

Just compiled a sample project for an APK. After changing the .APK extension to .zip and opening the archive I could see all the JavaScript sources.